# Trying to write to a CSV but some fields get excluded in scrapy for python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write to CSV but when I check the output, I see that some 'review' fields are left blank even though there when I see the output it prints it correctly. I believe this is a `zip()` limitation as I am using that to have it print column wise rather than 10 in a row. Again the Xpath output i print in spider outputs it correctly. Im wondering is it a limitaion of zip or my syntax? Or another guess it is maybe the `delimeter=','`.

Pipline.py

```
import csv
import itertools
from string import maketrans
class CSVPipeline(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('Output.csv', 'wb'),delimiter=',')
      self.csvwriter.writerow(['names','date','location','starts','subjects','reviews'])

   def process_item(self, item, ampa):

      rows = zip(item['names'],item['date'],item['location'],item['stars'],item['subjects'],item['reviews'])


      for row in rows:
         self.csvwriter.writerow(row)

      return item
```

Sample output, some reviews get excluded

```
names,date,location,starts,subjects,reviews
Aastha2015,20 July 2015,"
Bengaluru (Bangalore), India
",5,Amazing Time in Ooty,"
Hi All, i visited Ooty on July 10th, choose to stay in Elk Hills hotel, i read reviews of almost all good hotels and decided to try Elk Hills. I must say the property is huge, very well maintained. Rooms are clean spacious & views are great. Food in the Cafe Blue was awesome. They forgot to give us the...
"
pushp2015,11 July 2015,"
Gurgaon, India
",3,Nice Hotel ...under going maintainance,"
"
REDDY84,25 June 2015,"
Chennai, India
",4,Good old property,"
Its an old property with a very good view. We booked a suite at a very reasonable price but they charged for an extra bed 1500 + txs which i feel was not required because the bed was already their in the suite room.Other then that everything was good. Breakfast was nice . The room they had given was neat...
"
arun606,20 June 2015,"
Mumbai, India
",5,Amazing Hospitality,"
"
```

Comment: Some sample of the output and your items would be nice to see.

Comment: as you can see some of the reviews get cut out.

Comment: As I understand, the "cuts" are in the input data, not due `zip` or the writer...

Comment: yes, But I taught zip might not be able to handle the longer reviews.

Comment: I think it is zip because I when I do `print rows` it cuts it out but when I do `print item['review']` it prints it out correctly

Comment: After looking around I think it might be the `unicode` that might be tripping up zip

Comment: Try adding this before the zip, `print [(k, len(v)) for k,v in item.items()]`  It will show you the lengths of all of the items. They should all be the same.

Comment: Yeah no, names and location both have 12 and rest have 10. But reviews keep on fluctuating

Comment: I think the one's that are unicoded are being excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think what you call a limitation is more the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) way of working.

Check out [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) which will not stop at the shortest list.

Example:

```
>>> zip('abc', '12345')
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest('abc', '12345', fillvalue=0))
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), (0, '4'), (0, '5')]
```

Comment: This does not work as well it keeps on defaulting fillvalue even though there is data

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, As @Martin Evans stated I checked the lengths and found that There were many carriage returns that would simply put a blank space. i dont know why but it does. To fix it just add this code.

```
while "\n" in yourlist['key']: yourlist['key'].remove("\n")
```